# Website and Database Information

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, web

I would like to web host an e-shop to a server but I would like some clarifications. I have a database ready in another server.The website(e-shop) will be up to another server.The database on the other server is MSSQL 2000.So I would like to import all the data from the database to the website's database.Think is I need somehow to connect these 2 databases.Let me explain.I would like to transfer all the content with an automatic way from the database of the other server to the database of the website but I want to scan the database of the other server and whenever a change is made I would like my(website's) database with the same content to change automatically.Is this possible? Can you suggest any idea how can i do this?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

If the database is functional and currently hosted on a server then all you need to do is connect the new website to that database as well.

'Scanning' the database for new information isn't clear as the website will read all of the details from the database at its **current state** anyway.

Comment: I just need a windows server to connect the database that is on another server because is MSSQL right?

Comment: When you connect to the database you specify things like username, domain and password. You should be able to have your domain set as the address of the existing website and work from there. Have a try first and then post more specific problems.